# Catching TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I wonder if it's possible to catch the TypeError thrown when a user calls an instance method without instantiation. Something to allow me to write an exception message like:

`"Class instance is required for 'this_method'"`, instead of

`"Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"`.

Comment: This is a typical developer's error. What has the user to do with it?

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the term correctly. Someone using an API thinking it's a class method when it's not. The documentation should make this clear, but a better message could also be helpful

Comment: The error message should be reasonably understandable for any Python developer. The docstring of the method would be a good place to put additional hints.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple code snipped of Calc class with classmethod called addtwo that simply adds two numbers:

```
class Calc():
    a: int
    b: int
    
    def addtwo(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        return self.a+self.b
        
if __name__=='__main__':
        print(Calc.addtwo(a=2,b=4))
```

If you run this, you will get:

```
TypeError: addtwo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

which is the exact error that you encountered. According to your requirements, it can be easily fixed by enclosing the code inside a try-except block like this:

```
class Calc():
    a: int
    b: int
    
    def addtwo(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        return self.a+self.b
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        print(Calc.addtwo(a=2,b=4))
    except TypeError:
        print("Class instance is required for this_method")
```

and on running this, you will get:

```
Class instance is required for this_method
```

However, the standard way of calling a class method should be like this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    instance = Calc()
    print(instance.addtwo(a=2,b=4))
```

Hope it helped.